# Why does the specific conductivity against concentration curve for NaCl curve more than KCl?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, conductivity, salt

I understand why KCl has a higher specific conductivity than NaCl.. but I dont understand why the curvature is more significant for NaCl (KCl is a straight line). Ive provided a picture of this here, and this is also what I get from my experiment. Does anyone mind explaining why?[image]

Comment: Could you provide units for the abscissa?

Comment: Also, mS is not a unit of specific conductance (conductivity).

Comment: @BuckThorn this is a diagram i found online, i think it is mass %, im not sure. is specific conductance (conductivity) different than specific conductivity? i also got similar curves in my own experiment.. KCl was a straight line and NaCl was curving, where my y axis was micro siemen/cm and the x axis was mol/dm-3

Comment: Why don't they all start from the same data point at 0%?

Comment: @ManRow hmmm good point, i have no idea? any theories? do you think the greater curvature of NaCl is plausible? tbh im kinda unsure about the unit of the. y axis here and if it is the same as specific conductivity (which is siemen/m)

Comment: I remember very similar queation was asked within last months.

Comment: @Poutnik I also remember one. Can you find the link?

Comment: Could you provide a link to where you obtained the data?

Comment: @BuckThorn i found may pictures that show this type of curvature.. it's also what i got from my own experiment

Comment: Ok, the reason I asked is because the non-zero intercept is highly suspicious (actually, it doesn't make sense) unless there is some background electrolyte of course.

Comment: I think something is wrong. At 0% point, all lines must start from the same point. So an error has occurred.

Answer (score 2):

For equally charged ions a smaller radius implies a higher charge density, and therefore stronger Coulombic interactions with other charges in solution, including stronger ion-dipole interactions with water molecules, resulting in a more stable hydration sphere, and stronger interactions with counterions (here chloride). Such interactions reduce the mobility of the ion by opposing the effect of the applied external electric field, by either increasing solvent drag or generating an opposing electric field (see for instance this chem [libretext](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Book%3A_Chem1_(Lower)/08%3A_Solutions/8.10%3A_Ions_and_Electrolytes/8.10.9C%3A_8.10.9C%3A__Weak_and_Strong_Electrolytes) for an explanation). This slowing down can be interpreted as an increase in the hydrodynamic or Stokes's radius, and also results in a reduced diffusion coefficient, as shown in the following table (source CRC, $\pu{ 25^\circ C}$):

| Ion | $\Lambda_+ \pu{(10^-4 m2Smol^-1)}$ | $D \pu{(10^-5 cm^2s^-1)}$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $\ce{Cs+}$ | 77 .2 | 2 .056 |
| $\ce{Rb+}$ | 77 .8 | 2 .072 |
| $\ce{K+ }$ | 73 .48 | 1 .957 |
| $\ce{Na+}$ | 50 .08 | 1 .334 |
| $\ce{Li+}$ | 38 .66 | 1 .029 |
| $\frac12$ $\ce{Sr^{2+}}$ | 59 .4 | 0 .791 |
| $\frac12$ $\ce{Ca^{2+}}$ | 59 .47 | 0 .792 |
| $\frac12$ $\ce{Mg^{2+}}$ | 53 .0 | 0 .706 |
| $\frac12$ $\ce{Be^{2+}}$ | 45 | 0 .599 |

Therefore the smaller monovalent cation, $\ce{Na^+}$, and divalent cation, $\ce{Mg^{2+}}$, have *lower* molar conductivity than the species lower in the periodic table ($\ce{K^+}$ and $\ce{Ca^{2+}}$).

---

Additional comments:

(1) Instead of discussing NaCl or KCl, start discussing individual **cations** and **anions**, recognizing that these salts completely dissociate into ions in solution. Notice that the different salts share a common **anion** (chloride, Cl-). Therefore any differences are due to the choice of cation. Sounds obvious, but then you can look at everything from the perspective of the cation's interactions (even if those of the anion will also change between salts, and affect conductivity).

(2) Distinguish between the size of an ion before and after hydration. Bare (unhydrated) $\ce{Na^+}$ is smaller than $\ce{K^+}$, but hydrated $\ce{Na^+}$ is **bigger** than $\ce{K^+}$.

(3) Bigger bare (unhydrated) cation means **weaker** interactions and therefore **faster** mobility.

(4) What drives the formation of a larger hydrated ionic radius is deep down the same thing that drives interactions with other ions. The hydration shell is not that tight. Interaction with other ions will readily override them.

(5) Stronger interactions with other ions means more deviation from ideality. Ideality here means that individual ions behave the same (their mobility is the same) at all concentrations.

Comment: I thought KCl has a smaller hydrated ionic radii than NaCl though? I am using the molar conductivity values but Im just not sure why the slowing down affect is greater for KCl given it has a smaller hydrated ionic radii

Comment: @Riqueza $\ce{Na^+}$ interacts more strongly with other ions and this causes it to respond more strongly to an increase in concentration.

Comment: why does Na+ interact more strongly than K+ when it has a greater hydrated ionic radii? if I were to plot  specific conductivity  against concentration, should I expect a greater curvature for NaCl or KCl?

Comment: @Riqueza $\ce{Na+}$ interacts more strongly with other charges period. This includes charges on other molecules *or* charges on other ions such as chloride ion. As you increase concentration of chloride this means $\ce{Na+}$ has more ions to slow it down.

Comment: what concept could I use to substantiate or justify this? ive been researching into activity and ionic strength but tbh im kinda lost... i thought NaCl would interact the least tbh cause it has the largest hydrated ionic radii

Comment: @Riqueza Please see my additional edits to the answer.

Comment: [Ion association](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_association) should not be neglected.  *For example, magnesium sulphate exists as both contact and solvent-shared ion-pairs in seawater*

Comment: @Poutnik Thanks, you are probably right, although we are discussing chloride salts, and I am just trying to clarify some fundamentals. You are discussing a higher term in this expansion.

Comment: @buckthorn While I agree 2+2- salts have higher association tendency,  compare also Q concentrations versus Mg^2+/SO4^2- seawater concentration. Sure effects due ionic neighborhood comes first, but when concentration is high enough, solution gets quite crowded.